# Hide "title" with jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the HTML that is generated when using a script for some tabs, I do not have access to change the tabs with JavaScript, but I used some JavaScript to disable the drag and drop feature from working, but I can't seem to disable the "title" from displaying on hover event, any ideas ?

i set up jsfiddle for my attempt
http://jsfiddle.net/EjnEb/

I want the "Drag and drop this tab to re-arragne the order" removed when you hover each tab.

```
    <div id="homepagetabsdiv">
<ul id="homepagetabs">
<li class="currenttab" id="tab0" onclick="javascript:show_tab('0');">Home</li>

<li class="" id="tab1" title="Drag and drop this tab to re-arrange the order" onclick="javascript:show_tab('1');">managers</li>

<li class="" id="tab2" title="Drag and drop this tab to re-arrange the order" onclick="javascript:show_tab('2');">Standings</li>

<li class="" id="tab3" title="Drag and drop this tab to re-arrange the order" onclick="javascript:show_tab('3');">Game Day</li>

</ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just remove the `title` attribute?

```
$('#homepagetabs > li').removeAttr('title');
```

If you're new to jQuery or CSS selectors, the `#homepagetabs > li` part means "get all direct descendents of the element with the ID of `homepagetabs` which are `li`s".